# Compute base64 encoded hash from a given hash?

Tags: linux, unix, hash, openssl, base64

I created a file and input some random string into it.

```
touch tesseract && echo 'TestTestTestTestTest' > tesseract
```

Now if I use `openssl` to compute `base64` hash [`sha256`], I run this:

```
cat tesseract | openssl dgst -sha256 | openssl base64 -A
```

which returns me

`KHN0ZGluKT0gMzJjYjA1MTgzNDNhZmY2N2FlMmY5YzUwNDcwNGRiNGE5Njc5MzIyZWVlNTBmMjBiNTMzNjZlYTBiMDY2MWNlZgo=`

Now I process this hash stepwise, as,

```
cat tesseract | openssl dgst -sha256 > partialHash
```

which gives me

`(stdin)= 32cb0518343aff67ae2f9c504704db4a9679322eee50f20b53366ea0b0661cef`

Let this hash be `X`.
Then I do this,

```
echo '32cb0518343aff67ae2f9c504704db4a9679322eee50f20b53366ea0b0661cef' > partialHash
cat partialHash | openssl base64 -A
```

I get a different result. Why is that?

My reason for asking is because I use a binary, `hashdeep` which gives me hashes in form of `32cb0518343aff67ae2f9c504704db4a9679322eee50f20b53366ea0b0661cef` and I wish to convert them to `base64` encoded format as `hashdeep` is not capable of producing a `base64` output. So I pipe the intermediate hash to `openssl base64 -A`, but obtain a different result.

What am I missing? How can I convert the non-encoded hash `X` [which is `32cb0518343aff67ae2f9c504704db4a9679322eee50f20b53366ea0b0661cef`] to proper `base64` encoded format?

For simplicity purpose, we can assume that `X` is present in a file, 
created using `echo '32cb0518343aff67ae2f9c504704db4a9679322eee50f20b53366ea0b0661cef' > file`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not base-64 encoding the hash. You're base64-encoding the string

```
(stdin)= 32cb0518343aff67ae2f9c504704db4a9679322eee50f20b53366ea0b0661cef
```

(followed by a newline). Note the `(stdin)=` at the beginning. That's part of the string. That's going to have a different value than the base64 encoding of the string `32cb0518343aff67ae2f9c504704db4a9679322eee50f20b53366ea0b0661cef` (followed by a newline).

If your goal is to get binary hashes (rather than their string encodings), then use the `-binary` option to `openssl dgst`.

I'm not familiar with `hashdeep`, but when you say "non-encoded hash," that's not what it's generating. It's generating a hex-encoded hash. By the looks of it you're really looking for a hex-to-base64 converter. You can do that along these lines:

```
echo '32cb0518343aff67ae2f9c504704db4a9679322eee50f20b53366ea0b0661cef' | xxd -r -p  | base64
```

`xxd -r -p` converts a hex-encoded string into raw data.

(If you're using `openssl dgst`, just make sure that you're using options that don't inject `(stdin)=` on the front. My version of openssl doesn't do this, so I'm not certain what flag you'll need.)

Comment: Apologies for improperly​ phrasing the question. Thanks for understanding what I wanted to ask. I just tried it out and it worked perfectly. I was not familiar with `xxd` command. Thanks again.